# Contour graphs in JS or PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, graph, vector-graphics

```
 For a web application, I have to make a scientific graph.
```

You can see an example here :
http://www.ego-network.org/monitoring/plot_deployment.php?glider=eudoxus&deployment=Cascade&posti=4&postj=scaptemperature_lastweek&pposti=4&ppostj=scaoxygen_lastweek&hchk=&defsct=default_scatter

I have 2 coordinates, time and depth, and I want the temperature to be represent by a color, exactly like the example.
Someone know how to make this king of graph ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Google Charts and Visualization API is all Javascript, is very easy to use ad is hosted by Google.  Take a look at their gallery [here](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery.html).

Comment: Yes I have already saw a lot of a libraries (Google, Highchart, OpenChart ...), but no one can purpose me exactly the graph I want ! I will try to use PHP and GD...

Comment: You should take a look at [gRaphaël](http://g.raphaeljs.com/): the charting component of Raphaël JS library. You can generate pretty slick vector graphics with it and unlike Google charts, you have control over all the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the conrec algorithm from Prof. Paul Bourne. It is implemented in JS and PHP. You can also try my implementation of a contour plot (http://contourplot.codeplex.com). It uses some ideas from the AS3 implementation from indiemap contour plot.